# Using wget to download all zip files on an shtml page

Tags: linux, bash, download, wget

I've been trying to download all the zip files on this website to an EC2 server. However, it is not recognizing the links and thus not downloading anything. I think it's because the shtml file requires that SSI be enabled and that's somehow causing a problem with wget. But I don't really understand that stuff.

This is the code I've been using unsuccessfully.

```
wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.zip -erobots=off http://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/ftpdet.shtml#a2015_2016
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: The zip links aren't present on the source code, they're generated via javascript. The file list is located inside http://www.fec.gov//finance/disclosure/tables/foia_files_summary.xml under node `<fec_file status="Archive"></fec_file>`

Comment: @StanO: Take a look at: ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/2016/ ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/2014/ ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/2012/ ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/2010/ ... or ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zip links aren't present on the source code, that's  why you cannot download them via `wget`, they're generated via `javascript`. The file list is "located" inside http://fec.gov//finance/disclosure/tables/foia_files_summary.xml under node `<fec_file status="Archive"></fec_file>`

You can code a script to parse the `xml` file and convert the nodes to the actual links because they've a pattern.

---

**UPDATE:**

As [@cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) mentioned, the files are also on `ftp.fec.gov/FEC/`, you can use `wget -m` for mirroring the ftp and `-A zip` to restrict the download to zip files, i.e.:

```
wget -A zip -m --user=anonymous --password=test@test.com ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/
```

Or `wget -r`

```
wget -A zip --ftp-user=anonymous --ftp-password=test@test.com -r ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! In order to download just the zip files I was originally looking for, I need to go into the subfolders 1980 to 2014, (counting by 2). Is there an option I could add to do that? Also, can I combine the -A zip option to only download the zip files?

Comment: @StanO: With GNU bash 4: `for i in {1980..2014..2}; do echo ${i}; done`

Comment: Yes, you can use `-A`  to do that (tested), I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: @PedroLobito: So as I understand Cyrus' for loop, we'd affix the folder onto the ftp.fec.gov/FEC/ address such that the first is ftp.fec.gov/FEC/1980, etc. I don't know the syntax for doing this with bash, however :-(

Comment: @StanO: try this: `for i in {1980..2014..2}; do echo wget -A zip --ftp-user=anonymous --ftp-password=test@test.com -r "ftp://ftp.fec.gov/FEC/${i}"; done`. If everything looks fine remove `echo`.